# How to update a single item of a SliverList in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Do you guys know how can I update a single item of a sliver list without having to invoke a setState() ?

In my case I have a SliverList and i want to click into an item and change it's color, the problem using setState() is that it rebuilds the whole UI in a not smooth way and also mess up with Custom Scroll position.

The funny thing is that this SliverList behaviour does not occur when using normal ListView,  when use setState() on a ListView the load is smooth and it doesn't break the scroll state. Looks like the ListView can implicitely handle state better than SliverList.

But since I have a Custom Scroll I can't use ListVew it has to be SliverList

Any options ? Providers ?Notifiers ? Stream ? Bloc ?

Comment: Are you currently using any state management library? You can probably have an implementation that works within your state management approach. Also, please share your code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: If you want to reflect the changes on UI, you have call setState or stateManagement property, global key is also used for changing value.

Comment: setState() is not an option with SliverList because the reload of the screen is not smooth and it mess it up CustomScrollView position. About UI state management so far I was using ChangeNotifier combined with AnimatedBuilder (very simple approach and works fine), however, with Sliver List looks like I can't do this way, I will try to provide some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after all, I could solve my need using a simple ChangeNotifier combined with an AnimatedBuilder inside each item of the SliverList, I'll post some high-level code of the solution - it works just fine for my need!

```
class ChangeColorSliverListItemNotifier  extends ChangeNotifier {

  int index;
  Color current_label_color;



  ChangeColorSliverListItemNotifier()
  {
    this.current_label_color = Colors.white;
  }


  void onTap(int selected_index)
  {
        index = selected_index;
        
        this.current_label_color = Colors.yellow;
        notifyListeners();
  }



}



// code block inside SliverList items binding- changing only the color of the selected Widget

SliverList(
delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index)
{

return GestureDetector(
onTap:() {

  changeColorSliverListItemNotifier.onTap(index);

},
child:AnimatedBuilder(
    animation: changeColorSliverListItemNotifier,
    builder: (_, __) =>
        Row(children:[

            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right:8),
                child: Icon(Icons.edit,color:changeColorSliverListItemNotifier.index==index?changeColorSliverListItemNotifier.current_label_color:default_color,size: 20,)
      ),
      ])
    )
)   

....
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to use the [Riverpod state management library](https://riverpod.dev/), I made the following.

```
class SliverScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SliverScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        slivers: [
          _appBar(),
          _list(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  SliverFixedExtentList _list() {
    return SliverFixedExtentList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (context, index) => ListItem(index: index),
      ),
      itemExtent: 100,
    );
  }

  SliverAppBar _appBar() {
    return SliverAppBar(
      title: Text("Slivering..."),
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal[900],
      expandedHeight: 200,
      pinned: true,
      stretch: true,
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        background: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                Colors.teal[100]!,
                Colors.teal[600]!,
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

final colorStateProvider = StateProvider.family<Color, int>((ref, key) {
  return Colors.blue[100]!;
});

class ListItem extends HookConsumerWidget {
  final int index;
  const ListItem({Key? key, required this.index}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final colorState = ref.watch(colorStateProvider(index));
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => colorState.state = Colors.blue,
      child: Container(
        color: colorState.state,
        child: Center(
          child: Text("Item $index"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you click an item, it updates the color without rebuilding the whole list, only the item itself.

Comment: If you are not using Riverpod then this answer looks like overkill, but it is exactly what I needed.  The `family` provider with an `index` and updating the `colorState.state` to refresh the `ListItem` were the key insights.